Scipy Minimize Not Varying Optimization Variables as Supposed to
I am trying to optimize for a given date of deposit and withdrawal of a given commodity in a storage considering that the storage max capacity is 50 and the rate of injection/withdrawal is 5/day. Assume that it costs 0.01 per month to store the commodity. My commodity prices list is equally spaced in monthly dates.
At first I want to try to optimize for a single injection and withdrawal and next extend for multiples injections and withdrawals for the given timeframe I am analyzing.
So I created few constraint functions

withdrawal date > deposit date
total volume injected - total volume withdrawn < 50
volume injected = volume withdrawn
withdrawn <= 5 per day
deposit <= 5 per day

The profit function is given by
i. volume withdrawn * commodity_price[date_withdrawn] - volume injected * commodity_price[date injected] - cost*(date withdrawn - date injected)
The code is as follows:
##Volume in mm BBTUs
max_volume = 50
##Volume in mm BBTUs per day
rate = 5
##Cost in million dollars per day
costs = 0.01

commodity_prices = hw_nat_gas['Complete'].to_list()


from scipy.optimize import minimize


def constraint1(dates):
    deposit_date, withdrawal_date, volume_deposit, volume_withdrawal = dates
    return withdrawal_date - deposit_date

# Define constraint function for volume constraint
def constraint_volume(dates):
    deposit_date, withdrawal_date, volume_deposit, volume_withdrawal = dates  
    total_volume = volume_deposit - volume_withdrawal 
    return max_volume - total_volume 

def constraint_volume2(dates):
    deposit_date, withdrawal_date, volume_deposit, volume_withdrawal = dates  
    return volume_deposit - volume_withdrawal

def profit_function(dates):
    deposit_date, withdrawal_date, volume_deposit, volume_withdrawal = map(int, dates)
    profit = volume_withdrawal*commodity_prices[withdrawal_date] -     volume_deposit*commodity_prices[deposit_date] - costs*(deposit_date-withdrawal_date)
    return -profit

def withdrawal(dates):
    deposit_date, withdrawal_date, volume_deposit, volume_withdrawal = map(int, dates)
    return rate - volume_withdrawal

def deposit(dates):
    deposit_date, withdrawal_date, volume_deposit, volume_withdrawal = map(int, dates)
    return rate - volume_deposit

constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_volume},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': withdrawal},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': deposit},
               {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : constraint_volume2}]

bounds = [(0, 58), (0, 58), (0,5), (0,5)]

initial_guess = [7, 12, 0, 0]

result = minimize(profit_function, initial_guess, bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

At first what I am getting is that there is no variation in the dates of deposit and withdrawal, it simply optimizes for the initial guess, the value i am inserting in the scipy.minimize function. Second, it is not varying as well the volumes for injection.
If I instead of using initial guess of [7, 12, 0, 0] use [7, 12, 5, 5] the value of the profit increases, but i wanted the function to perform this analysis by itself, by varying the parameters and obtaining the combination of values that get the max profit.
Any suggestions?

Look at dates, in any of your functions, before converting to int.  It probably is a 4 element array of floats, and differs from the initial guess by fractions. If so, any variabilty gets lost in the map/int step.

It in fact only supports int values

minimize doesn't know this.  It works with floats.

Now i tried setting the bounds to 0, 0.5, 0, 0,.5, 0,0.58, 0,0.58 But then the solver varies only the 10th decimal place instead that the first and second, so it doesnt generalize as well to the bound area

Perhaps scipy.optimize.brute() might be a better option here? You can tell it to try all integer values. minimize() is a local minimizer which needs information about the slope of the function to optimize. If the function is only defined at integer coordinates, it can't find slope.
